# Is there function for computing percentage change for each month in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) table as follows (imported from excel) [image]

From this, I would like to obtain percentage change for 'Total' based on month.

```
eg. 
((2020-01-2019-01)/2019-01)*100
((2020-02-2019-02)/2019-02)*100 etc.
```

For now, I have come up with following function.

```
def TotalChange (last_year,current_year):
    return((float(current_year)-last_year)/(last_year))*100
```

Are there any functions which will automate this pattern and how I can derive those figures and put them in a table?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['monthly_perc'] = df['Total']/ df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.to_period('M'))['Total'].trasnform('sum')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.